# How to list all the items related to a certain category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to display all the items related to a certain category when the relevant category name is clicked from the navigation panel.
This is my navigation panel

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><%=link_to "About us" ,pages_about_path %></li>
     <li><%=link_to "Contact us" ,pages_contact_path %></li>
        <% @categories.each do |category| %>
                <li><%=link_to category.name,category %><br></li>
        <%end%>
    </ul>
```

This is the code for my show view for categories

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <h1><%= @category.name %></h1>
        <div>
            <% @items.each do |item| %>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <%= link_to item.title,item,class:"btn btn-primary btn-block" %>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                Quantity  :<%= item.qty %><br>
                                Price  : <%= number_to_currency(item.price, unit: "RS " ) %><br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                <%= link_to "Edit" ,edit_item_path(item) , class: "btn btn-default" %>
                                <%= link_to "Delete" ,item , :confirm => "Are you sure?" , :method => :delete , class: "btn btn-danger"%>
                            <hr>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <%end%>
```

This is the method at the categories controller.

```
def show
  @category =Category.find(params[:id])
  @items = Item.all
end
```

When i use these blocks all the items are being displayed .

This is how the database tables are

```
class CreateItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :items do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.float :qty
      t.decimal :price
      t.integer :category_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@items = Item.all` returns *all items irrespective of a category*. You need to change it to `@items = @category.items`

```
def show
  @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  @items = @category.items
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Categories Controller show should be changed as below:

```
def show
  @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  @items = @category.items #Item.all returns all items irrespective of a category
end
```

Before doing this, make sure there is a has_many and belongs_to association defined in category model and item model,

In Category model (category.rb),

```
has_many :items
```

In Item model (item.rb),

```
belongs_to :category
```